# 3Sum using for in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I had this classic algo exercise: How many triples sum to zero in this array? No problem implementing this in Java:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
  (for int j= i+1; j < array.length -1; j++) {
    (for int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
      if (array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
}
return count;
```

How would I do that in Clojure though? I asked myself: How can I do nested loops in Clojure.

But [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137660/how-do-you-replace-java-nested-for-loops-in-clojure) doesn't really address my problem, as it takes two identical arrays and combines all the elements (also the identical elements, e.g. 1 and 1).

Related question: How do I get all combinations of triples from a collection?

Note: We were explicitly asked not to sort the array. I know that there are faster algorithms for this.

EDIT: Added "== 0" to condition.

Comment: The sample Java code actually returns how many triples do NOT sum to zero ...

Comment: Thanks @marco.m for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

also you can do it with list comprehension, without operating indices at all:

```
user> (def data [1 -2 1 1 -3 2])
#'user/data

user> (defn tails [data]
        (take-while seq (iterate rest data)))
#'user/tails

user> (for [[x & xs] (tails data)
            [y & ys] (tails xs)
            [z] (tails ys)
            :when (zero? (+ x y z))]
        [x y z])

;;=> ([1 -2 1] [1 -2 1] [1 -3 2] [-2 1 1] [1 -3 2] [1 -3 2])
```

Comment: Very nice! I would suggest replacing `seq` with `not-empty` in the `take-while`, for readability.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `for` loop in clojure, similar way as in java.

**1. Calculate only the count of combinations that sum to 0,**

```
(defn three-sum-count [array]
  (let [three_sum
        (for [i (range 0 (- (count array) 2))
              j (range (+ 1 i) (- (count array) 1))
              k (range (+ 1 j) (count array))]
          (if (zero? (+ (get array i) (get array j) (get array k))) 1 0))]
    (reduce + three_sum)))
```

**REPL examples,**

```
user=> (three-sum-count [1, -2])
0
user=> (three-sum-count [1, -2, 1])
1
user=> (three-sum-count [1, -2, 1, 1])
3
user=> (three-sum-count [1 -2 1 1 -3 2])
6
```

**2. List all combinations that sum to zero,**

```
(defn three-sum-combinations [array]
  (remove empty?
           (for [i (range 0 (- (count array) 2))
                 j (range (+ 1 i) (- (count array) 1))
                 k (range (+ 1 j) (count array))]
             (if (zero? (+ (get array i) (get array j) (get array k)))
               [(get array i) (get array j) (get array k)]
               []))))
```

**REPL examples**

```
user=> (three-sum-combinations [1, -2])
()
user=> (three-sum-combinations [1, -2, 1])
([1 -2 1])
user=> (three-sum-combinations [1, -2, 1, 1])
([1 -2 1] [1 -2 1] [-2 1 1])
user=> (three-sum-combinations [1 -2 1 1 -3 2])
([1 -2 1] [1 -2 1] [1 -3 2] [-2 1 1] [1 -3 2] [1 -3 2])
```

you can also calculate how many combinations this way,

```
user=> (count (three-sum-combinations [1 -2 1 1 -3 2]))
6
```

Comment: To be a bit more accurate, `for` is not a looping construct in clojure. It is a list comprehension construct.  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for